# C# NUnit Specify which test classes to run

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a use case where I need to specify a list of test classes to run.

Each test class has x number of tests. I need to make custom test suites which run only the specified test classes.

Is there anyway to do this? Will they still show in the Test Runner?

Comment: You want to run them in IDE or via CLI or programatically?

Comment: programatically. Will the results show up in the Test Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `Categories` [docs](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/category.html):

> The Category attribute provides an alternative to suites for dealing
> with groups of tests. Either individual test cases or fixtures may be
> identified as belonging to a particular category. Some runners,
> including the Console Runner, allow specifying categories to be
> included in or excluded from the run. When categories are used, only
> the tests in the selected categories will be run. Those tests in
> categories that are not selected are not reported at all.

Example:

```
  [TestFixture]
  [Category("CategoryA")]
  public class CategoryATests
  {
    // ...
  }
```

And the dotnet test cli has a `--filter` flag:

```
dotnet test --filter <Expression>
```

The give an example only for mstest Example:

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=CategoryA
```

but it also tell that it supports nunit filtering with `FullyQualifiedName, Name, Priority, TestCategory` try that out.